# How do I make a sql query where fields are the result of a different query?

Tags: sql

I have two tables,

the first is like this:

```
f1 | f2 | f3 | f4
-----------------
data....
```

the second contains info about the fields of the first:

```
field | info
------------
 f1      a
 f2      b
 f3      a
etc.
```

I would like to query the first table selecting the fields with a query on the second. So, for example, I might want to get data for fields where info is equal to "a", thus I would do "select f1, f3 from first_table". How do I do this programmatically? I was thinking about something along the lines of `select (select fields from second_table where info='a') from first_table`

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Check `SQL JOIN`, DB relationships and "normalization". Storing field values as column names (or vice versa) is a bad idea.

Comment: I suggest clarifying with example data that might be in both tables so that we can make more informed suggestion for how to fix what looks like a broken structure.  "Data" is just a bit too vague.  As BalusC mentions, you should probably look into the concept of normalization for making better database structures in the future (or getting a co-worker to make better structures). e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't treat strings as field identifiers in SQL, just can't be done. The only way would be to first run the first query and then construct another SQL query based on the first's results.

Even so, sounds like you're doing things in a wrong way. Maybe you should describe your practical application so people can suggest better ways to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run the first query and use the data to construct a dynamic query that can then be run to get the data that you want. This is often used when you need a pivot query, where the number of fields is not known beforehand.